# Python logging not happening

Tags: python

I have a python script for deleting records from DB tables. Some of the tables are having huge volume, like 500M records. There are log statements after every delete statement. But log statements are not getting printed, but delete statements are getting executed as i can see data being purged in DB.

Below is the code snippet:

```
 del_query = "delete from {source_schema}.RAW_TAB where raw_tab_id in " \
            "(select RAW_TAB_ID from {source_schema}.RAW_TAB_1 where T1_ID in ({t1_list})) " \
            .format(source_schema=source_schema, t1_list=t1_list)
logger.info("Deletion iteration started from source")
logger.debug("Executing query :\n {} for ".format(del_query))
cursor.execute(del_query)

del_query = "delete from {source_schema}.RAW_TAB_1 where T1_ID in  ({t1_list}) " \
    .format(source_schema=source_schema, t1_list=t1_list)
logger.debug("Executing query :\n {}".format(del_query))
cursor.execute(del_query)
```

In the above statement, `t1_list` is comma separated values, like `t1,t2,t3` etc. I pass in collection of size 50. So, accordingly several records are supposed to be deleted from these tables with large volumes. The sample code given here are part of method and the method is called several thousand times, until all the records are deleted.

So, want to understand why log statements are not printed but subsequent delete statements are getting executed properly. When i run the script, i am not sure if purge is happening or not , until i query in DB.
When i use the same script to purge tables with less volume, purge happens properly.So, the issue is when the table is having large volume. Is there any limit to string format method of python that it can accept only string of certain length? Or is there any issue with logging implementation.

Log declaration is as follows:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('sspurge.' + __name__)
```

Python version used in 3.8

Answer (score 0):

Check the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) for more information about logging.

You are not seeing any log messages because you forgot to change the logging level of the Logger instance to `DEBUG`. The default level is `WARNING`, so only `WARNING` messages and more severe messages (`ERROR` and `CRITICAL`) will be printed.

If you also want to print `DEBUG` and `INFO` messages, you need to add the following line after creating the Logger instance:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('sspurge.' + __name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```